# Elastic Beanstalk Immutable Deployments failing due to 4xx codes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, elastic-beanstalk

We've been having issues with elastic beanstalk immutable deployments failing and rolling back due to high numbers of requests that result in 4xx codes hitting the load balancers during the environment update.

Since the product in question is an access management system, 4xx codes (especially 403 and 404) very much indicate correct operation of the system and thus are false positives in the context of the health checks.

Can anyone point me in the direction of configuring the health checks to ignore 4xx codes, or even turning off the healthchecks during EB deployments completely? Unless i'm missing something the main EB docs are not very helpful in this matter.
Any help / advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried IgnoreHealthCheck + HealthCheckSuccessThreshold that are described at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalkcommand ? Also you can play with HealthCheckInterval/HealthyThresholdCount

Comment: Hi, yes, I should have mentioned the stacks are being managed via cloudformation and unfortunately those properties don't currently appear to be supported.